# High-side current sensor causing feedback oscillations during overcurrent

Tags: current-measurement, feedback

I'm trying to design a circuit which uses an INA138 current sensor to shut off a load during overcurrent conditions (max current = 1A).

However, when the current is over 1A I'm creating a feedback loop between the sensor and the comparators I'm using for the logic. I'm trying to use the discharge on an RC filter to hold the logic on the second comparator to LOW to delay readings but I don't know how to turn the first comparator off while this happens so that it can fully discharge.

Is there a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do here?

This is my schematic:

[image]

This is a .zip file with my LTSpice circuit and the INA138 spice model if needed:

https://easyupload.io/j1hv8u

Comment: I guess you want an RC filter that charges quickly and discharges slowly (or the reverse - doesn't matter)? You can incorporate a diode into the filter to create asymmetry. (At that point I'm not sure it qualifies as a filter in the DSP sense, but that's just semantics)

Comment: @user253751 - that's what I've tried to do but it's not much use placing between the two comparators. How were you thinking the RC filter could be connected to prevent the feedback?

Comment: Your power symbols are logically upside down

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - what do you mean by that?

Comment: My idea would be to use a 555 timer in a monostable configuration. However, I am not versed in this type of application. Maybe it can be done with less components.

Comment: @p.chives, hi, discharging the excess current which exceed more than 1 Amp using a capacitor to store its energy is not that right, you should use a synchronous buck converter which uses PWM to adjust the current output and its much more efficient for current over 1A until 5A :)

Answer (score 0):

During overload, the INA138 will generate higher voltage so the 1st comparator will output zero. C1 will discharge to ground through R8 and once its voltage drops below 4V (this will take time) the 2nd comparator will try to turn the BJT, and thus the PMOS, off.

This will make the overload conditions no longer available. So the INA138 will generate lower voltage, thus the 1st comparator will output 5V so the capacitor C1 will be charged through R8. Once its voltage exceeds 4V the M1 will be turned on again.

So what you designed is a delayed current limiter, so this might bring oscillations. Without the RC network, the circuit would turn into a constant current source (i.e. active limiter) and the oscillations would be more frequent but with smaller amplitude.

Something like a 555-based monostable multivibrator might be a better choice here:

- The output of the 1st comparator can drive the multivibrator's input to zero so the multivibrator can generate a delay.
- From the multivibrator's output you can turn the load switch, M1, off so it can stay off for the delay.

Remember that even if the 1st comparator's output hits high again the multivibrator will not stop.

Comment: oh no not the 555 without a design spec 1st

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to define current limits;

1. Current threshold and tolerances
2. Time duration to ignore or integrate with a LPF time constant
3. Linear current limiter with series pass controlled loss (Rce or RdsOn)
4. Overcurrent protection (OCP) method  a) transient b) latched c) delayed reset

You have suggested your Specs are:

1. +1 Amp
2. RC Time limited current trip and restore

   - If you have positive feedback, it will latch and negative feedback , it will oscillate with cause stable oscillations with an "overload that is sustained" , such as you have shown with switched 15V/10 ohm load = 1.5A  You can reduce that oscillation period with a long period like 1 second using a "1-shot cct".
   - If you have a long probe ground lead, a fast pulse edge will cause ringing from probe resonance. Make that ground contact or spring clip to chip test point gnd < 3 cm somehow. I remove 10:1 probe tip and gnd clip and use probe pin & ring between two test point pins such as 1/4 resistor leads cut and soldered or inserted in breadboard with IC decoupling caps.

- We can estimate your feedback polarity by counting signal inversions for rising current to voltage sense.

  - (-) Current Sense Out
  - (-) Inverting input U2
  - (+) Non-inverting input U3
  - (-) Q1 B-C
  - (+) M1 G-S  (source follower)

    ====
  - (-) total thus negative feedback with RC delay so it will oscillate
- to make fast-attack slow decay or 1-shot we can use long RC=T and short RC with a diode in parallel with R in the desired polarity. Then choose R and RC to achieve OFF and ON latency specs that you define with large R and small C's considering bias leakage as well.  If you want to trigger fast and retry , this is commonly described in different ways but basically **allows cool-down so an automatic retry with a continuous fault is low duty cycle.** such as 1 second.
- If this is your plan, then you can proceed otherwise add/correct details in your design spec 1st.
- After design, verify the function of each component with range and tolerances
- for example. R4= 0.1 ohm * 1 A = 0.1V so you can choose a 0.1V reference.
- But **instead, you have 0.19 V** with 5V R7/(R6+R7), so verify what you want.
  U2 is your OCP fault="0" logic output, so you can use **any logic after** that to control FET as desired but you also want to add some Input ENABLE signal.

### [Simple one shot  with RC turn on & off time for LPF effect](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0Y2AsBOJyWoGwkZNAOA7AExxwxoICMCOYArCAMx1MQ0CmAtOeQFAAmIBGhnIYCRECIEherAGYBDAK4AbAC7cAxgJw4JonSDRxwEyAQ54JcSDgJgCjPAnrwa9qDB4AnbbvZxdAgNJCHJYcO4ScglyAj0BcUlonAAdAGdyGnTOLIzwmHTyawRSQjAyNAIqcnpC6xxURuRC-PB0uxb88Il0sG4Ac19DYyDdahM+gCUTf10IdiMJzFC6CDXIGm4fGmIQdno4neM1qB4AdxAjvYDL3f24vu3dxavYuYlNwdeg2+Mi4-A3DslhoCDi90uYL242MADUvHIgWAQbsWLETMYAJJpdjcWSYRYHX4MOL0eimZjcC6vDBXNbcTLRei4EkE4xEuIPD7cAAeDDw8zCmDglnYlj+cUysPSygA9v0AJYadIAcjgPI1vMwIDwohuTm16NlAAdWAA7dIaWXKZSsDSqWVedIAYVlAFtjfIvPIHU60gA5AAK-vSjvS-o0AAt0gqzcbFOpgTFSXFxkSsTikSjjBCaOiIRmUsaqQwWZJRvECNw0qXdG9MEkfqEQAplGlWCXvro4I25ltaxIfi4Je8wvlNAORBAe8I0CdyBw68UmihyDhomBoGAeEnh4PAoR99rYbxeFmZjcIbNj6fzxXr-eYSAT2ek1dr++ny+SzOj7+p4CFzMnWQ5lnOgEDjcwFHucxI3Fciw8Fo8w3IKGChBYViQCuSCEAg6FbjwgwnKE6GAny9AGmE4p2DE06DtICppPIABGtolmIfyiGAugcp2UK5lCEBVj4gizkMIQSF0WpEBgnAwJgeDROwCDigIxgABJKgA1ooxqWooXgImaqgygqboKqorBeP275EqC4JEqEsC2QJRJoEIexOVYJQwAMhieRCHlyZJfRJlwXLjPR8KIj4aFLOsnjcLKEjDBi1ECIlsCqcFggmJKDDJYYaWhC4oIeEgBxOC4lHbjguDkpulUENVYC1WuDWpXEGD0Nw9BjCAABiG4fFJezRJMrBpExqjyGaGgdkAA)

Using ~ 1s hickup time

[image]

### PWM , or OCP ?

https://e2e.ti.com/support/motor-drivers-group/motor-drivers/f/motor-drivers-forum/850885/faq-overcurrent-protection-ocp-vs-current-regulation

Rather than show you how to use the INA, I showed you how to design a high side current sensor using simpler methods